# Как сделать popover на Bootstrap 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть блок с описанием внизу. Сейчас сделано так, что при клику на абзац описание всплывает в popover и при клике вне этого места - прячется. Как сделать так, чтобы этот текст можно было выделить? Сейчас он прячется при попытке выделить текст.

```
<p class="excerpt" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-trigger="focus" data-content="<?php echo $excerptcat ?>" data-placement="top">
    <?php echo substr($categories_item->description, 0, 40) ?>
    <br><span>Read more</span>
</p>
<script>
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если уберете `data-trigger="focus"` то поповер будет прятаться только при повторном клике на параграф и вы сможете выделить текс.

Как вот [тут](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo-1)

Comment: Да, но нужно именно чтобы он исчезал, когда кликнешь в любом другом месте и + к этому еще и копировался :)